# std::chrono::ceil alternative prior to c++ 17

Tags: c++, c++17, c++-chrono

Is there an alternative for `std::chrono:ceil` in a c++ version prior to c++ 17?

I want to round a time_point to it's minute ceiling (i.e. nearest minute).

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/ceil

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> time_point_now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

auto start_time = std::chrono::ceil<std::chrono::minutes>(time_point_now);
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `std::chrono::ceil` was extensively field tested prior to standardization in order to prove its usefulness.  That field test implementation is still available [here](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) as a free, open-source, header-only library which works with C++11/14:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <chrono>

int
main()
{
    auto time_point_now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto start_time = date::ceil<std::chrono::minutes>(time_point_now);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One a bit verbose way of doing minutes-ceil (but using just `<chrono>`) is:

```cpp
time_point_now += std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(
    (time_point_now + std::chrono::minutes(1)).time_since_epoch()) -
    time_point_now.time_since_epoch();
```

Full example with output to console:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/jYcGh97vx)

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    auto time_point_now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    auto Out = [&]{
        auto in_time_t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(time_point_now);
        std::cout << std::put_time(std::localtime(&in_time_t), "%Y-%m-%d %X")
            << std::endl;
    };

    Out();
    time_point_now += std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(
        (time_point_now + std::chrono::minutes(1)).time_since_epoch()) -
        time_point_now.time_since_epoch();
    Out();
}
```

Output:

```
2022-01-04 12:07:23
2022-01-04 12:08:00
```

---

One may convert solution above into handy `TimeCeil()` templated function, that is exactly what you're looking for:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/rz4166751)

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

template <typename Unit, typename TimePoint>
inline TimePoint TimeCeil(TimePoint const & tp) {
    return tp + std::chrono::duration_cast<Unit>(
        (tp + Unit(1)).time_since_epoch()) - tp.time_since_epoch();
}

int main() {
    auto time_point_now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    auto Out = [&]{
        auto in_time_t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(time_point_now);
        std::cout << std::put_time(std::localtime(&in_time_t), "%Y-%m-%d %X")
            << std::endl;
    };

    Out();
    time_point_now = TimeCeil<std::chrono::minutes>(time_point_now);
    Out();
}
```

Output:

```
2022-01-15 10:31:10
2022-01-15 10:32:00
```

In both code snippets above ignore complex `Out()` lambda function, it is not needed for you, it is a way to output formatted time to console, just for example.

---

As [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70573479/stdchronoceil-alternative-prior-to-c-17/70578581?noredirect=1#comment125032138_70578581) by @HowardHinnant, if you care about strictly handling very rare case when time point is exactly equal to multiple of minute, then I did small fixup such that ceil of minute-multiple time is equal to initial time (and not plus 1 minute):

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/d8nddsW96)

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

template <typename Unit, typename TimePoint>
inline TimePoint TimeCeil(TimePoint const & tp) {
    auto const res = tp + std::chrono::duration_cast<Unit>(
        (tp + Unit(1)).time_since_epoch()) - tp.time_since_epoch();
    if (res == tp + Unit(1))
        return tp;
    return res;
}

int main() {
    auto time_point_now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    auto Out = [&]{
        auto in_time_t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(time_point_now);
        std::cout << std::put_time(std::localtime(&in_time_t), "%Y-%m-%d %X")
            << std::endl;
    };

    Out();
    time_point_now = TimeCeil<std::chrono::minutes>(time_point_now);
    Out();
}
```

Output:

```
2022-01-16 11:43:00
2022-01-16 11:43:00
```

Comment: When the input to `ceil<minutes>` is at a minute, `ceil` should behave as the identity function.  But `TimeCeil` adds a minute. https://godbolt.org/z/xTWvqbW8q

Comment: @HowardHinnant Just updated my answer to include suggested by you fixup (as separate code snippet) so that ceil of multiple of minute time point is equal to initial time point and not plus 1 minute.